# How to direct user to a custom path after executing a Views Bulk Operations action?

Tags: views

I have created a custom action as described at https://www.drupal.org/node/2052067. My question is how to direct the user to a custom path after executing the action?

Answer (score 0):

Its like altering normal form using `hook_form_alter`:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_form_MYVIEW_page') {
    $form['#action'] = '/my/target'; // the url that is displayed when in VBO multistep

    if (!empty($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'])) {

      if (in_array('views_bulk_operations_form_submit', $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'])) {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_vbo_redirect';
        $form['actions']['cancel']['#href'] = 'my/target';
        $form['actions']['cancel']['#options']['path'] = 'my/target';
        dpm($form);
      }
    }
  }
}

function MYMODULE_vbo_redirect($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = array('my/target');
}
```

Comment: It did not work. I have created a custom action form as described in the tutorial mentioned above.